# Custom attributes are removed when using custom blots

Tags: quill

I created a custom blot for links that requires to be able to set `rel` and `target` manually. However when loading content that has those attributes, quill strips them. I'm not sure why.

I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/riedemann/pen/dZbqoB?editors=1111) to illustrate the issue.

This is my custom blot:

```
const Inline = Quill.import('blots/inline')

class CustomLink extends Inline {
  static create(options) {
    const node = super.create()
    node.setAttribute('href', options.url)

    if (options.target) { node.setAttribute('target', '_blank') }
    if (options.follow === 'nofollow') { node.setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow') }

    return node
  }

  static formats(node) {
    return node.getAttribute('href')
  }
}

CustomLink.blotName = 'custom_link'
CustomLink.tagName = 'A'
Quill.register({'formats/custom_link': CustomLink})
```

Do I have to tell Quill to allow certain atttributes?

Answer (score 4):

Upon initialization from existing HTML, Quill will try to construct the data model from it, which is the symmetry between `create()`, `value()` for leaf blots, and `formats()` for inline blots. Given how `create()` is implemented, you would need `formats()` to be something like this:

```
  static formats(node) {
    let ret = {
      url: node.getAttribute('href'),
    };
    if (node.getAttribute('target') == '_blank') {
      ret.target = true;
    }
    if (node.getAttribute('rel') == 'nofollow') {
      ret.follow = 'nofollow';
    }
    return ret;
  }
```

Working fork with this change: https://codepen.io/quill/pen/xPxGgw

I would recommend overwriting the default link as well though instead of creating another one, unless there's some reason you need both types.